# Access 2000 database growing fast

Tags: ms-access, merge, ms-office

We have an Access 2000 format database running in Office Access 2003.

However we have a problem with the size: when I merge the database, the size is about 250 mb.

2 days later, the size is 3 double about 750 mb.

How can I see where this increase in size comes from? Can I look behind the scenes in Access? The database is running for a tennis club and our employees are working all day long with the database. Another programmer made the database and says it is common to Access the increase in size.

How can I start to figure this out?

Comment: What do you mean, when you "merge" the database?

Comment: Try http://dba.stackexchange.com/ They might provide a better answer.

Comment: Sorry Robert, I mean compact the database.

Answer (score 0):

An MS Access database can increase in size from. amongst other things:

- normal operations
- importing data
- deleting and recreating tables rather than deleting records and refilling
- using a database that is not split
- using DAO to create tables ( http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B197953 )
- design work